# How to flip array only if value not exists?

Tags: php

For example i have an array like

```
$keys = array(
             'host', 
             'port' => 3306, 
             'database', 
             'username', 
             'password'
             );
```

In `PHP` it looks like this

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "host"
  ["port"]=>
  int(3306)
  [1]=>
  string(8) "database"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "username"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "password"
}
```

What is the best way to flip it that it would be like this

```
array(
     'host' => NULL, 
     'port' => 3306, 
     'database' => NULL, 
     'username' => NULL, 
     'password' => NULL
     )
```

Basically I need to flip only those element, which don’t have values (in this case only port has).

Comment: to me expected result isn't flipped. is it?

Comment: @DonCallisto nope, the main thing is that all element except `port` is values, not keys.

Answer (score 2):

may be below code will do it as per you mentioned in question. But its not a flip.

```
$keys = array(
         'host', 
         'port' => 3306, 
         'database', 
         'username', 
         'password'
         );

foreach ($keys as $key => $val) {
  if (is_int($key)) {
     $keys[$val] = NULL;
     unset($keys[$key]);
  }
}
var_dump($keys);
```

#### Its doing the following steps

1. loop over the array
2. checking whether its a numeric key if so does 3 and 4
3. create a new index in array with the val in numeric key pointing to NULL
4. finally unsetting the old numeric index from the array

Answer (score 0):

An alternative proposal for you, which I want to post because i think you're suffering from [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

```
<?php
$defaults= array(
     'host' => null
     'port' => 3306, 
     'database' => null, 
     'username' => null, 
     'password' => null
     );

$customizations = array(
     'host'=> 'localhost'
);

$params = array_merge($defaults, $customizations);
/* $params is now this:
   array(
     'host' => 'localhost'
     'port' => 3306, 
     'database' => null, 
     'username' => null, 
     'password' => null
     );
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$keys = array(
    'host', 
    'port' => 3306, 
    'database', 
    'username', 
    'password'
);

$counter = 0;
$a = [];
foreach ($keys as $key => $value) {
    if($key == $counter) {
        $a[$value] = NULL;
        $counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        $a[$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($a);
```